# Php get variable from another file

Tags: php, variables, include

I am quite new to php and I would like to know how I can get a variable from one file to another.

For example I would like to use a variable `$email` that is set in a `Login.php` file and use it in a Candidate.php file.

The problem is that in the Login.php file I initialize this `$email` variable `$_POST` data, Therefore I doubt that I can can use `include()` on another page to access the variable.

My question is, could I use `include()` to use my variables on a different page than the one they are declared on; or what are some efficient way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Question Is Unclear.

Comment: well, you have answers below; ask them. Personally, I think the ones given so far were just a wee-bit too fast on the trigger if you ask me and without knowing exactly which animal(s) we're dealing with here.

Comment: Ha  Ha `:D` *Your Dialogues Are Un-Beatable* Fred.

Comment: Well, least I made "one" person smile today and that's all that counts @NanaPartykar ;-) and was all well worth it.

Comment: Addendum to my *"Personally, I think the ones given so far were just a wee-bit too fast on the trigger..."* comment. One of them is by far a better answer. Can you guess which one? ;-)

Comment: You specifically mentioned that you couldn't just include a file to get the variables, so I used that as a cue on how you would like to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways you could do this, I will share 2 with you.

**INCLUDE**

You can in fact `include()` it using a 3rd file, but I don't recommend that as sessions are much easier. But this is useful if you want a config type file aswell.

top of login.php:

```
include('global.php');
```

New file: global.php

```
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
         session_start();
    } //start sessions if it isn't already started.
    if(isSet($_POST['email'])) { //Check if email variable is POSTED
         $email = $_POST['email']; //Set session variable "Email" to the posted data.
    }
```

top of candidate.php

```
include('global.php');
```

You'll want to include the global file before anything containing $email is written. The other bright side of this method is that you only really need to start sessions once (if you start them in the global file), because when you include it on other pages, it takes care of itself.

---

**SESSIONS**

At the top of any page that you want to access a global variable, you could use sessions.

Top of login.php:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
} //start sessions if it isn't already started.
if(isSet($_POST['email'])) { //Check if email variable is POSTED
     $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email']; //Set session variable "Email" to the posted data.
}
```

on Candidate.php:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
} //start sessions if it isn't already started.
echo $_SESSION['email']; //You can call this variable on any page that has sessions started
```

---

Hope I helped you!

Comment: Good answer, yet *"my 2 cents"*: It's best to also check if the session is set/not empty for Candidate.php (or all files using sessions) as that may produce false positives and/or potential errors.

Comment: I will add that as well, as I always do it on my own sites to avoid that annoying notice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple aproach to this are the session variables:

check this: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: This is not an answer. Please, avoid giving suggestions as answer. Use comment box.

Answer (score -1):

Your Data Store in session in variable required for sort time

Comment: This is not an answer. Please, avoid giving suggestions as answer. Use comment box.